# Why does my while loop iterate quickly from 3 to 0 without allowing user to attempt again?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am creating a login form which is limited to only 3 attempts then redirects the user. However, it quickly iterates from 3 to 0 at only 1 failed try then redirects the user. I have been trying but have been stuck at this.

Javascript loginUser code which runs upon submit:

```
  function loginUser() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) {

  var atmp = 3;
  while(atmp > 0) {
      if(output == 'TRUE') {
           console.log("Success");
           form.reset();

           break;
      }
      else if (output == 'FALSE') {
           console.log("Denied");
                
                atmp--;
                form.reset();

                Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Wrong Username/Password! Please, try again.',
                showCancelButton: false,
                });
   
              }         
  } if (atmp == 0) {
           console.log("3 Failed attempts!");
           // Redirect code here...

     

  } 

}).checkLogin(username, password);  

}
```

Code.gs checkLogin function:

```
    function checkLogin(username, password) {
    var url = 'sheetLinkHere';

    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("users");
    var find = webAppSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().find(([, , c, d]) => c == username && d == password);
    return find ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    }
```

I tried placing the while loop at different parts of the code but still wont work for me.

Comment: where do you think the code should "pause"?

Comment: @JaromandaX I wanted it to "pause" at each wrong login credentials.

Comment: is output a string or boolean?

Comment: at which line of code did you expect to "pause"? anyway, there's nothing that changes the value of `output` ... so if it's `FALSE` it stays `FALSE` in that while loop

Comment: @DCR as it is seen in the Code.gs it returns a string of either "TRUE" or "FALSE".

Comment: @JaromandaX is there a way for that to change? I have been trying to figure out how to limit it to 3 attempts, I tried resetting the input fields but it won't asked for user input and still iterate from 3 to 0 at one wrong attempt.

Comment: yes, change your code, but since I have no idea what `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` is, then you'll need to figure it out

Comment: You have no call to loginUser inside of the loop.

Comment: How would the user no when to try to login again

Comment: It's very likely that the problem is caused by having `var atmp = 3;` and the` while` inside the `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` callback. I think that you have to move the `atmp` declaration  into the client-side global scope. By the other hand using while doesn't look to be appropriate in this case, instead use an if statemente. If you need further help, please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix it. Credits to @Ruben in the comment section for giving me an idea. I just placed the variable outside the function and used an if-statement instead.

```
var atmp = 2;


function loginUser() {
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) {

  if(atmp == 0) {  

   //redirect code here...

  }else if(atmp > 0) {

      if(output == 'TRUE') {
          console.log("Success");
          form.reset();
      }
      else if (output == 'FALSE') {
           console.log("Denied");
           atmp--;
      }  
  }           
 }).checkLogin(username, password);      
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```js
const
  realPassword = "Melon",
  input = document.querySelector('input'),
  feedback = document.querySelector('span');

input.addEventListener('change', handlePasswordAttempt);
input.focus();
let attempts = 3;

function handlePasswordAttempt(event){
  --attempts;
  const attemptedPassword = input.value;
  input.value = "";
  input.focus();
  
  if(attempts == 0){
    feedback.textContent = "No login for you!";
    input.setAttribute("disabled", "");
  }
  else if(attemptedPassword == realPassword){
    feedback.textContent = "Qapla'!";
    input.setAttribute("disabled", "");
  }
  else{
    feedback.textContent = `Incorrect password. ${attempts} tries left.`;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Enter password:<input></div><br/>
<div><span></span></div>
```